# Can't Pull/Fetch using VS Team Explorer(Bitbucket git)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, bitbucket, team-explorer

I am getting an error in my VS 2017 Team Explorer whenever I pull/fetch or push.

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn /C/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No error
could not read Password for 'https://<myusername>@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled.
```

I tried to set my password by indicating:

```
https://<myusername>:<mypassword>@bitbucket.org
```

Still not fixed. But when I used SourceTree, it is fine.

How can I fix this so I can able to use VS Team Explorer again for pull/push?

I am using the following:

- VS 2017 Community 15.7.6
- Git version 2.18.0
- Bitbucket

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extension for Visual studio unknown error - unable to push or fetch anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725278/extension-for-visual-studio-unknown-error-unable-to-push-or-fetch-anything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem in Git for Windows and Microsoft is monitoring the solution to release a new version of VS with the patch.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/266473/sync-commit-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error.html

----- Finally I resolved with these steps --------------

1) delete credentials in the Credential Manager

2) rename or delete the Git directory in "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer"

3) install the package "https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.17.0"

4) when VS asks for the BitBucket credential insert them

Only these sequence worked for me.

Comment: This did not work for me but modifying step 2 fixed it: rename or delete the Git directory in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017{Community|Professional|Enterprise}\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git"

Comment: When I deleted the "Team Explorer" directory I had to do a VS repair to get team explorer back. and I was still broken. When I deleted the "Git" directory it solved the problem

Answer (score 10):

Same here, I do believe it's from bitbucket side.

the following worked for us :

Remove **git** related Credentials stored in Windows Credentials in >>Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

link to SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git/20195558)

then use this command :

`git remote set-url origin https://name:password@bitbucket.org/repo.git`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password) is the source for this one

Comment: After an hour of pulling my hair out, this solved it for me

Comment: @p3tch are you able to use VS Team Explorer for push/pull/fetch?

Comment: @JericCruz After applying this fix, yes

Comment: This works, but it's very insecure to store the password in plain text like this. SSH key authentication is the way to go.

Comment: Really nice fix for me.

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket's Authenticator is currenty failing. There is an open issue about it. https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/16892/cannot-fetch-or-push-using-visual-studio

If you can take the risk of pure username:password format using for temporarily, it will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it's an epic fail. Our team too is blocked

Answer (score 1):

I solved by using **git-credential-store** for now. I think it might be the best way at this moment. As I mention in this link [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/16888/git-auth-problem).

This is link here is how to use **git-credential-store**. If you want to have "git credential store" globally. You may use below command:

> git config --global credential.helper

In fact, you save your username and password in your local. It will ask your username and password only one time.

Otherwise, you can use **SSH** (it does not work on my VPN).